# Calling an instance method from a lambda given as an argument to a constructor

Tags: java, lambda, constructor

I have a class `Foo`  and `TryFoo`

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Foo {

  Consumer<Integer> c;

  public Foo(Consumer<Integer> e) {
       this.c = c;
  }

  void bar(){}

}


class TryFoo{

   public static void main(String... args){

      Foo e = new Foo((someInt)-> /*how do i reference bar?*/ );

   } 
}
```

How do I call the method `Foo#bar()` from the lambda? I tried using `this.bar()`, `Foo.this.bar()` but to no avail. A setter is another way but using a constructor is preferable.

Edit 1: `Foo#bar` isn't static.

Comment: Well you haven't constructed `Foo` yet so I don't see how you can reference `bar()`.  Did you meant to use a ctor and not a regular method?

Comment: Do you mean `bar` to be static here?  That way, you can call it before you construct your `Foo`.

Comment: There is no way your `bar()` will fit a `Consumer<Integer>`. Unless you are doing something else in lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't without making `bar` static:

```
  static void bar() {}
```

and calling it with:

```
  Foo e = new Foo((someInt)-> Foo.bar());
```

Otherwise, there is no way to call an instance method without an instance object to call it on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `BiConsumer`.

```
public class Foo {
  BiConsumer<Foo, Integer> c;

  public Foo(BiConsumer<Foo, Integer> c) {
       this.c = c;
  }

  void bar(){}

  public void useConsumer(int i) {
    c.accept(this, i);
  }
}


class TryFoo {
   public static void main(String... args) {
      Foo e = new Foo((foo, someInt)-> {
        // Do something with someInt
        foo.bar();
      });
   } 
}
```